# alert returns: Account created for "undefined" everything works just fine

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, materialize

hello there i am currently following a tutorial with firebase and firestore, everything works just fine, except when i register a new user my alter message says: Account created for undefined

my code looks like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default {
  name: 'register',
  data: function(){
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    register: function(e){
      firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        .then(
          user => {
            alert(`Account created for ${user.email}`);
            this.$router.push('/');
      }, err => {
      alert(err.message);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

the result is as expected new user is created but i cant get the undefined message right ?

Answer (score 0):

i found the error, in the alert i can use: `${user.user.email}` or 'Account...' `+ this.email`, but still looking for the theoretical explanation....